# What material are professional football nets made from?

Tags: football, equipment

What material are English Premier League football nets made from?

I'm doing some research and am keen to know  and better still, who makes nets.

Comment: Generally, polyethylene.  Will answer properly if I get time later.

Comment: This is not an answer, but I think it's an interesting comment. The Laws of the game, located here: http://www.fifa.com/mm/Document/FootballDevelopment/Refereeing/02/36/01/11/LawsofthegamewebEN_Neutral.pdf, do not actually require a net. They just say that nets may be used as long as they are properly supported and do not interfere with the goalkeeper.

Answer (score 3):

Net goal should be made of **hemp, jute, nylon or polypropylene**.

Here some commercial links: [1](http://dir.indiamart.com/impcat/football-nets.html) - [2](http://www.sportsystem.it/en/categoria-prodotto/games/soccer-and-reduced-soccer/nets-for-standard-and-reduced-soccer-goals/) and [some more info](http://www.dsr.wa.gov.au/support-and-advice/facility-management/developing-facilities/dimensions-guide/sport-specific-dimensions/football-%28soccer%29) (take a lok at goals section)

Answer (score -4):

The material mostly used is high quality square mesh cotton material which ensures that it resists wear and tear.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this answer?

Comment: In India this type of nets are used!

Comment: For professional matches? In any case, please provide a link or quote from a reputable third party which supports your assertion.